# Column sort method in helper class is working on one table but not another in same app

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sorting, helper

trying to work out why this (what I would assume to be simple) functionality isnt working.

Quick background, this app was made by another company and I have been brought in to make some changes to the ui and bits of functionality. I have been learning the system, and the framework it was built in simultaneously (Laravel 5.1). The whole thing is running in a docker container.

Table Helper class

```
<?php
namespace App\Helpers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class TableHelper {
  public static function uriColumnSorter($label, $sort, $color = '#758292') {

    $str = \Request::url();

    //get the variables in the url e.g. sort: col name, direction: asc
    $data = \Input::all();

    //if there is a _url var in the url, unset it
    if (isset($data['_url'])) {
        unset($data['_url']);
    }

    //the column to sort, set to the param passed in
    $data['sort'] = $sort;

    //Either set to desc if direction already exists and is asc, or set to asc
    $direction = $data['direction'] = (isset($data['direction']) && $data['direction'] == 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';

    //build query out of the data array if it has values
    if (count($data) > 0) {
        $str .= '?' . http_build_query($data);
    }

    //throw an a tag back with a link with the sorted query
    echo '<a href="' . $str . '" style="color: ' . $color . '">' . $label . ' <i class="fa fa-sort-alpha-' . $direction . '" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-left: 12px;"></i></a>';
}
}
```

So great, you call this where needed and it spits out an a tag that sorts the table based on the column. Here is an instance of it being used where the sort works

```
<table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-md-3">{{ \App\Helpers\TableHelper::uriColumnSorter('Col Label', 'model.value_wanted') }}</th>
                <th>Another Col</th>
                <th>Last Col</th>
...
```

Seems straight forward, the example of it not working has a table of the same layout, and I put the helper method call in the same exact way, just with swapped data names.

The function calls, and the sort link in the table header is there and is clickable. It just doesnt change the sort.

What could be stopping this from working? Do I need an indication that the column is sortable in the model somewhere? Or perhaps docker needs to force update? Would not think so because the method executes but I am unsure, docker is new to me.

Thank you in advance!